# Can I stay overnight at Košice airport or does the terminal close?

Tags: airports, sleeping, slovakia

I have a flight at 5:35 AM  from Košice (KSC). Unfortunately I'm 2.5 hours away by train, and the first train in the morning doesn't get in until 4:10. I don't think this is sufficient time to get a taxi to the airport (first bus doesn't leave until 4:40), check in, check my bag, and get to my gate.

So my other option is to go the night before. The last train arrives around 11pm. If I get a taxi to the airport, **can I stay in the pre-security area overnight?** Does the terminal building actually close at some point? Will I get hassled by security/the police and asked to leave?

The last flight out is between midnight and 1 AM. The last flight in is around the same time. The first flight in is at 4 AM, so there's no regularly scheduled air traffic between 1 and 4 AM. I couldn't find anything about hours of operation save for one random person's comment that the pre-security area is public space open 24/7 -- but I'd like confirmation before attempting.

Comment: Have you checked the website sleepinginaiports ?

Comment: Yep. There's no reviews for Košice and they solicit emails from anyone who's done so.

Comment: Kosice train station to Kosice airport is a mere 10km. Why not take a cab?

Comment: There are also hostel rooms for as little as 15 euros.

Comment: I'd rather not gamble on the train being on time and there being cabs hanging around the train station at 4:00 AM.

Comment: Depending on your airline carrier, you can probably check-in and obtain boarding passes 24 hours earlier than scheduled departure time.

Comment: I slept in airports in my 20s. Would not do it again. Sleep in an hostel at walking distance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I couldn't find any information about opening hours on the [official website](http://www.airportkosice.sk/), I've received a reply from their [official Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Letisko-Ko%C5%A1ice-Airport-Ko%C5%A1ice-as-265716963518688/):

[image: opening hours facebook]

Rough translation:

> - Is the airport open overnight?
> - Yes, the airport is open non-stop

So the answer is **yes**, you can stay at the airport overnight.